# Bing API does not returning always same information in Europe (postal codes among others)

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

While using API `https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/` from Bing some of the queries return an object like this:

```
address: {addressLine: "9 Rue Charles de Gaulle", adminDistrict: "Centro-Valle del Loira",…}
addressLine: "9 Rue Charles de Gaulle"
adminDistrict: "Centro-Valle del Loira"
adminDistrict2: "Indre y Loira"
countryRegion: "Francia"
formattedAddress: "9 Rue Charles de Gaulle, 37600 Saint-Senoch"
locality: "Saint-Senoch"
postalCode: "37600"
```

And some other queries return an object with less properties:

```
address: {adminDistrict: "Centro-Valle del Loira", adminDistrict2: "Indre y Loira", countryRegion: "Francia",…}
adminDistrict: "Centro-Valle del Loira"
adminDistrict2: "Indre y Loira"
countryRegion: "Francia"
formattedAddress: "Saint-Senoch, Indre y Loira, Francia"
locality: "Saint-Senoch"
```

What could be the reason? It do not think it is related with data becase the addressLine looks like a common property for any call, same with PostalCode, every place has a postal code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got information coming from Microsoft about this:

> If you want to make sure Postal Code is returned each time using
> reverse geocoding, you must add includeEntityTypes patameter into URL.
>
> For the Spanish address it will be :
>
> [https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/40.704765412488385,-5.129651691971695?key={Bing](https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/40.704765412488385,-5.129651691971695?key=%7BBing)
> MapsKey} &includeEntityTypes=Postcode1

Answer (score 1):

Check the result for match confidence and the type of the object returned. When you ask for an address that can't be fully resolved the service will return the closest available match which may be an entire region, admin district or postal code. Obviously an admin 1 region match won't have an address line or even postal code as it covers a large area.

Comment: Thanks, the confidence did not work for us as we are getting medium in lots of places but we finally end up using entityType looking for "Address" so I'm accepting the answer.